# org-mime add caption to exported images

Tags: html, email, emacs, export, org-mode

I am using org-mode to write and send emails. In my org buffers I sometimes have images that contain captions through  `#+CAPTION:` (https://orgmode.org/manual/Captions.html). These are, as of yet, not processed in the `org-mime-org-XXX-htmlize` calls. I would like to include these captions in the export.

HTML has the  and  elements that can be used for this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption), but I'm not entirely sure where to start extending the functionality of org-mime to use these to solve my problem, or whether that is currently even possible.

Any advice?

Looked at the internal code-base of org-mime. Didn't find an answer.